# ElasticSearch. How to get '_score' field of hit?

Tags: javascript, node.js, elasticsearch

I have the following code :

```
export const getUserIds = async (search) => {
  const requestBody = {
    query_string: {
      query: `*${search}*`,
      fields: [
        `firstName^${FIELD_PRIORITIES.FIRSTNAME}`,
        `lastName^${FIELD_PRIORITIES.LASTNAME}`,
        `username^${FIELD_PRIORITIES.USERNAME}`,
      ],
    },
  };
  const resultOfElastic = await client.search({
    ...ES_CONFIG.INDEX,
    ...ES_CONFIG.USER.TYPE,
    body: {
      query: requestBody,
    },
    size: 1000,
  });
  const orderedHits = _.orderBy(resultOfElastic.hits.hits, ['_score', 'desc']);
  return orderedHits.map((user) => stringToObjectId(user._id));
};
```

Because ES doesn't sort result on `_score` field I need to do it in code. The result from ElasticSearch is `resultOfElastic.hits.hits` and every hit has `_score` field. I try to use Lodash to order hits by `_score`, but nothing happens. How to sort hits by field `_score`?

Comment: ES by default sort results based on `_score`

Comment: @NishantSaini I also read it on official page, but in practice I had another result. I tried to write in query ```{ sort : [ { _score : 'desc' } ] }```, but nothing happens also

Answer (score 0):

you can use bool query to sort on the basis of _sort

```
{
    "from": 0,
    "size": 50,
    body: {
      query: {
        bool: {
          must: [{

              match:{
                 "firstName":${FIELD_PRIORITIES.FIRSTNAME}`,
                 "lastName":${FIELD_PRIORITIES.LASTNAME}`,
                 "username":${FIELD_PRIORITIES.USERNAME}`,
              } 
          }, ],
          should: [{
            match:{
              "meta": searchString
            } 
          }, ]

        },

      },
      sort: {
        _score  : {
          "order": "desc"
        }
      },

    }
  }
```

details of bool can be found [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.4/query-dsl-bool-query.html)

Comment: What do I need to write in `must.match`?  Your example doesn't work

Comment: you have two options inside "must" you can write one field that must be matched and the other fields can be defined under "should".